# Passing values between form-With constructor-Error comes!-C#-Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor

When i am passing values from the one form(Form1) to other form(Form2) Via constructor
and when i click button to pass value error comes NULLRefrence error was unhadled!
Please tell me what do.i search on internet same codes comes ,but the error comes.

Form2 Constructor

```
public Form2(string ab)
    {

        textBox1.Text = ab;


        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Form1 ,On button click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 obj = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        obj.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textBox1` is only created by `InitializeComponent`.

Before you call `InitializeComponent`, it's `null`.